# Is "Attached are two documents...One for marking reference on where the signature is signed" grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm writing an email to a client asking him to sign a paper.

> Attached in the email are two documents. One for marking reference on where the signature is signed. The second...

I am just wondering if the sentence

> One for marking reference on where the signature is signed.

is grammatically correct. If not, what's wrong? If yes, isn't it a run-on sentence in the first clause "One for marking reference"? How can we fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure if we really need a document to explain where the signature should be signed, though it might be possible if the documents are very complex. At least, you should have a verb, e.g. *"One **is** for marking reference ..."*, otherwise it will be a fragment (which is not exactly wrong by itself, but fragments are uncommon afaik in technical writing). Another way is to make them a list, i.e. *"Attached in the email are two documents: one for ..., the other for ..."*

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to say. Are you saying that the client needs to sign both documents, or they only need to sign one, and the other document shows where they need to sign on the other one?

Comment: @DamkerngT. you have answered my question. I was thinking if I need "is" for the sentence. Thanks.

Comment: I converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to describe each document in a standalone sentence, you should have a verb, for example, *"One **is** for marking reference ..."*. Otherwise, it will be a fragment. (A fragment is not wrong by itself, but fragments are uncommon, as far as I know, in technical writing).

Another way is to make them a list. For example,

> *Attached in the email are two documents: one for ..., the other for ...*

Answer (score 0):

The context is not clear.The beginning of sentence"So"  is not correct,because it

is used to give the reason why something happens,why someone does something etc:

the other  "attached to mail" is correct .

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but it should be a comment rather than an answer.